# Updating one filed of a pair using ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Consider a pair of Value and Counter which is added to a list via `ArrayList`. I want to search for a new value and insert is if it doesn't exists, or increment its counter if it exists.

```
class foo {
  private String val;
  private int count;
  public foo( String s, int c )
  {
     val = s;
     count = c;
  }
}

public class bar {
  public void method1() {
  {
    ...
    List<foo> myList= new ArrayList<foo>();
    String nValue = getFromUser(); // assume it is a working method
    int pos = myList.indexOf( nValue );
    foo f = new foo( nValue, 1 );
    if ( pos == -1 ) {
      myList.add( f );
    } else {
      myList.set( pos, ????? );
    }
  }
}
```

In order to write the ?????, I have this in mind

```
else {
  foo f2 = new foo( f.getValue(), f.getCounter()+1 );
  myList.set( pos, f2 );
}
```

and absolutely, I have to define `getValue()` and `getCounter()` in `foo{}`. Is there any better and more efficient way to do that?

---

Another question is about `indexOf()`. It seems that it doesn't find the position of existing item! The following code shows that the pos is -1 although the request string (hello1) exists in myList

```
class foo {
  private String st;
  private int count;
  public foo( String s, int c ) 
  {
    st = s;
    count = c;
  }
}
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<foo> myList= new ArrayList<foo>();
    myList.add( new foo( "hello1", 1) );
    myList.add( new foo( "hello2", 1) );
    int pos = myList.indexOf( "hello1" );
    if (pos == -1)
      System.out.println("not found");    //goes here!!!
    else
      System.out.println("found");
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking if there's a more efficient way of creating getters?

Comment: Basically, I am asking how to change the counter (one field) while the value (other field) is unchanged.

Comment: is `val` should be unique or can exist multiple times?

Comment: No it is unique

Comment: why you don't use a Map then `Map<String, Integer>`?

Comment: Because I will expand that pair later for more fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not correct `int pos = myList.indexOf( nValue );`, instead to solve you have to search for your Object, for example you can use a separated method which search to your object here is a piece of code can help you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<foo> myList = new ArrayList<foo>();

    String nValue = getFromUser();
    int pos = getPosition(myList, nValue);//<-------Get position in your List
    foo f = new foo(nValue, 1);
    if (pos == -1) {//if your object not exist create it and add it to your List
        myList.add(new foo(nValue, 1));
    } else {//else increment your counter
        myList.get(pos).setCount(myList.get(pos).getCount() + 1);
    }
}

private static int getPosition(List<foo> myList, String nValue) {
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
        if (myList.get(i).getVal().equals(nValue)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Your class foo, should implement getters and setters for example :

```
class foo {

    private String val;
    private int count;

    public foo(String s, int c) {
        val = s;
        count = c;
    }

    public String getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public void setVal(String val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

You ca find an example here [Ideone](https://ideone.com/soolXj)

Comment: yes @mahmood the problem is in `indexOf` so instead replace it with the method that i already mention in my answer this should help you ;)

Comment: @mahmood it is getters and setters of your attributes in your class `foo` check my edit

Comment: I think `f.setCount(f.getCount() + 1);` is redundant.

Comment: no no @mahmood `f.setCount(f.getCount() + 1);` mean that you should to increment the old count, so to increment it you have to get the count then you have to set the new count this is equivalent to `int c = f.getCount(); f.setCount(c + 1);` get it?

Comment: Weird. The line above that (`myList....`) updates the counter inside the arrayList. That `f` which news a foo is only usable when pos=-1. Check the code please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142636/discussion-between-mahmood-and-ycf-l).

Comment: @mahmood As I said in my comment, there is no "in the list." You do not appear to understand how references work.

Comment: @mahmood yes this is correct it was a typo, this line `f.setCount(f.getCount() + 1);` is useless you can remove it :) https://ideone.com/soolXj

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider i think it was a typo you don't need to use `f.setCount(f.getCount() + 1);` because i already change the element in the list, so `f.setCount(f.getCount() + 1);` is useless sorry

Answer (score 0):

Simply create getters and setters for each field. This is common practice in Java.

Then use:

```
foo f = myList.get(pos);
f.setCounter(f.getCounter()+1);
```

Comment: I think your statements will modify the pair outside of myList since you extract the pair first. I want to update the counter inside myList.

Comment: No, it will not. It will return a reference, and you modify the reference. It does not return a copy.